# golang exec.Command cause a lot of defunct processes

Tags: go, pptp

I'm using golang to call pppd and then kill it after a while. However I got a lot of defunct proccesses in this way.

This is how I run pppd

```
exec.Command("sh", "-c", "pppd call vpn").CombinedOutput()
```

This is how I kill it.

```
exec.Command("sh", "-c", "pkill pppd").CombinedOutput()
```

Then I got a lot of this

```
root     31541 23536  0 10:54 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     31929 23356  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     31933 23356  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
root     31940 23356  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     31993 23536  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     31997 23536  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
root     31998 23536  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     32012 23356  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     32016 23356  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
root     32017 23356  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     32070 23536  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     32074 23536  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
root     32075 23536  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     32083 23356  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     32087 23356  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
root     32089 23356  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     32131 23536  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     32135 23536  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
root     32148 23536  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     32160 23356  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     32164 23356  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
root     32165 23356  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pppd] <defunct>
root     32177 23536  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pptpgw] <defunct>
root     32181 23536  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 [pptpcm] <defunct>
```

How can I avoid defunct processes.

Comment: Perhaps the shell is not reaping the child process, although I don't knw why it wouldn't.  Try invoking the commands directly: `exec.Command("pppd", "call", "vpn").CombinedOutput()`.

Comment: This is [issue 18874](https://golang.org/issue/18874). The latest docs make note of this: `Wait waits for the command to exit and waits for any copying to stdin or copying from stdout or stderr to complete`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These ["zombie" processes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) are created when a process has finished, but the parent has not read their exit status via the `wait` system call.

I would guess that all you need to do is call `(*Cmd).Wait()` on every command structure you create. Obviously This will be less straight forward than you may like, since you probably don't want to call `Wait` on the first command until after the second command is finished.

---

EDIT: As is pointed out in the comments, [`(*Cmd).CombinedOutput()`](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=13634:13680#L486) calls [`(*Cmd).Run()`](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=8356:8381#L275), which calls `(*Cmd).Wait()`... So the above is wrong. The real answer in this case is that for some reason `sh` isn't cleaning up, and so the solution is to cut out the midle man and do the call like so:

```
exec.Command("pppd", "call", "vpn").CombinedOutput()
```

That'll teach me to read the docs a little closer next time...

Comment: Actually .CombinedOutput() already has called wait(). I guess the wait() is onlying waiting for `sh` instead of the child processes  sh created. Do you know how to resolve this ?

Comment: If that is the case, no. Well, yes. Start the command directly, without `sh`, eg `exec.Command("pppd call vpn").CombinedOutput()`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to cancel your command would be to use [exec.CommandContext](https://godoc.org/os/exec#CommandContext). e.g.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
exec.CommandContext(ctx, "pppd", "call", "vpn").CombinedOutput()

// in some other goroutine...
cancel()
```

Maybe this would solve your zombie problem?

Answer (score 0):

run subprocess in a new thread

```golang
go exec.Command("sh", "-c", "pppd call vpn").CombinedOutput()
```

kill subprocess

```
exec.Command("pkill", "pppd").CombinedOutput().CombinedOutput()
```